# потеря значения поля C#

Tags: c#

```
    namespace DZ_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TeamLeader pr1 = new TeamLeader();
            pr1.Condition();//проверяем состояние стройки: построен или нет фундамент
            Basement bsm = new Basement();
            bsm.Installation();
            pr1.Condition();//проверяем состояние стройки: построен или нет фундамент (ОПЯТЬ ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ, ЧТО ФУНДАМЕНТ НЕ ПОСТРОЕН)
        }

        class TeamLeader
        {
            public void Condition()//метод для проверки состояния строительства
            {
                House b = new House();
                b.Condition();//метод для проверки постройки фундамента
            }
        }

        class House : TeamLeader
        {
            private int Bsement { get; set; }

            public new void Condition()
            {
                if (Bsement == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Фундамент построен");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Фундамент не построен");
                }
            }

            public void Result(int b)
            {
                Bsement = b;
            }
        }

        class Basement : House
        {
            public void Installation()//отрисовка фундамента
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Солнце всходит - пора за работу!");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                Console.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("_");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("I");
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 48; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("I");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
                }

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("-");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Стоп!");
                Result(1);//передаем флажок об окончании строительства
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

При повторном вызове метода Condition() экземпляра TeamLeader pr1, после отрисовки фундамента и установки флажка об окончании строительства, метод опять возвращает 0, то есть "фундамент не построен". В чем загвоздка и как это исправить?

Comment: Каждый раз, обращаясь к `Condition` вы создаете новый экземпляр дома с нулевым значением `Bsement`.

Comment: понял - как сделать так, чтобы актуальное значение можно было достать?

Comment: @Proshka: В зависимости от смысла, конечно. Вам же надо не заткнуть ошибку, а сделать как правильно? Например, у меня есть подозрение, что конструировать внутри базового объекта `TeamLeader` экземпляр производного `House` скорее всего неверно. Опишите более подробно вашу задачу.

Comment: 1. Есть прораб - он должен контролировать состояние постройки дома 2. Дом состоит из частей: фундамент, стены, крыша, окна 3. При запросе прораба, нужно получать инфу, что уже построено, то есть состояние строительства

Comment: Окей, почему тогда у вас `House` наследует `TeamLeader`'у? Наследование означает по сути «дом является разновидностью прораба», что очевидно не так.

Comment: Вам надо посмотреть как более правильно реализовывается паттерн проектирования "Строитель"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Паттерн «Прораб» же!

Comment: спасибо, я так понял, что нужно изначально выстроить правильную архитектуру

Comment: @Proshka да. почитайте, посмотрите паттерны. занятная вещь)

Comment: уже открыл - читаю, действительно, зачем изобретать велосипед. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Прораб и дом — отдельные сущности. Прорабу могут дать *задание* заняться домом. Фундамент тоже не является домом, никак.
2. Дом включает в себя фундамент.
3. Не дело главной программы создавать фундамент. И не дело фундамента устанавливать самого себя в дом.

Это выливается в такой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    House house = new House();
    TeamLeader pr1 = new TeamLeader();
    pr1.WorkOnHouse(house);
    bool hasBasement = house.Basement != null;
    if (hasBasement)
        Console.WriteLine("Фундамент есть");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Фундамента нет");

    pr1.ConstructBasement();

    hasBasement = house.Basement != null;
    if (hasBasement)
        Console.WriteLine("Фундамент есть");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Фундамента нет");
}
```

Теперь прораб.

```
class TeamLeader
{
    House house;  // текущая стройка
    // посылаем на объект
    public WorkOnHouse(House house)
    {
        this.house = house;
    }
    public ConstructBasement()
    {
        if (house == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Сначала направьте на стройку");
        if (house.Basement != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Да есть уже фундамент, чё совсем ку-ку?");
        Basement basement = new Basement();
        basement.Construct(); // строим
        house.Basement = basement;
    }
}
```

Теперь дом. Он простой как... угол дома!

```
class House
{
    public Basement Basement { get; set; }
    // тут будут другие части дома
}
```

Ну и фундамент.

```
class Basement
{
    bool IsConstructed { get; private set; } = false;

    public void Construct()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Солнце всходит - пора за работу!");
        // и так далее
        Console.WriteLine("Стоп!");
        IsConstructed = true;
        // Result(1); // это не нужно, не дело фундамента ставить флаги
    }
}
```

Comment: Кто поставил минус, нельзя ли обосновать?

Answer (score 4):

Тут у вас ничего не теряется просто ОБЪЕКТЫ `bsm` и `pr1` никак не связаны, и как следствие изменения в одном никак не отображается на другом. Кроме того у вас довольно странная архитектура наследования - фундамент наследует зданию, а прораб включает в себя здание (наверное в качестве третей ноги). Тут пожалуй для фундамента следует использовать композицию, а прораба переработать в интерфейс.

Comment: прораба переработать.......в колбасу за такое)

Comment: просьба не судить строго - я только учусь

Comment: @Mirdin Спасибо за ответ - посмеялся от души с собственного кода